# disbale default widgets on theme activation

Tags: widgets

I want to deactivate all default widgets on theme activation which are active by default for new WordPress installation.

I'm using following function as callback for theme activation :

```
if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == 'themes.php' ) {
    // 
}
```

By default activated widgets are :

1. Search
2. Recent Posts
3. Recent Comments
4. Archives
5. Categories
6. Meta

I don't want to deregister them  permanently but hide from the sidebar.

Is that possible ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default widgets are not usually activated with the theme. Themes add default widgets in the sidebar template file. For example take a look at twenty ten sidebar.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the primary and secondary widget areas.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */
?>
<div id="primary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <ul class="xoxo">

<?php
    /* When we call the dynamic_sidebar() function, it'll spit out
     * the widgets for that widget area. If it instead returns false,
     * then the sidebar simply doesn't exist, so we'll hard-code in
     * some default sidebar stuff just in case.
     */
    if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' ) ) : ?>

            <li id="search" class="widget-container widget_search">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </li>
            <li id="archives" class="widget-container">
                <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'twentyten' ); ?></h3>
                <ul>
                    <?php wp_get_archives( 'type=monthly' ); ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="meta" class="widget-container">
                <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'twentyten' ); ?></h3>
                <ul>
                    <?php wp_register(); ?>
                    <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                    <?php wp_meta(); ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <?php endif; // end primary widget area ?>
    </ul>
</div><!-- #primary .widget-area -->
```

as you can see the default widgets (which in this case are: search, archives and meta) are hard coded inside a `dynamic_sidebar` conditional check to see if this sidebar has any widgets set by the user.

So to answer your question make sure your sidebar file has no default widgets inside the `dynamic_sidebar()` conditional check.

**Update:**

I'm strongly against removing the configured and saved widgets of a previously used theme and think that you should not do it but if you must then you can catch the theme activation and trigger a simple function to clear saved widgets ex:

```
if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == 'themes.php' ) {
    add_action('admin_footer','removed_widgets');
}


function removed_widgets(){
    //get all registered sidebars
    global $wp_registered_sidebars;
    //get saved widgets
    $widgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets');
    //loop over the sidebars and remove all widgets
    foreach ($wp_registered_sidebars as $sidebar => $value) {
        unset($widgets[$sidebar]);
    }
    //update with widgets removed
    update_option('sidebars_widgets',$widgets);
}
```

Comment: I agree with you. But my issue is I see pre-activated widgets for my fresh wp-installation inside Appearance=>widgets=> "any-sidebar-1" as listed above. How to remove them on theme activation ?

Comment: @MANnDAaR i updated my answer.